# How To Visualize a Weighted and Directed Country-to-Counry Trade Network?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

I'm trying to figure out the best package to visualize a trade network among 50 countries. The visualization would have the following properties:

1. each node represents a country and the size of the node reflects the total trade (throughput) of that country
2. connecting and directed lines between nodes reflect the amount of import/export through thickness

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try FlowMapper, http://www.csiss.org/clearinghouse/FlowMapper/